# <apex:inputField value is not Editable

Tags: salesforce

I'm making an app using Apex.I have an Apex form that requires to update an Invoice inputField value each time I click Update button in the VF page. I can see the value once I add the id of the Invoice record. But I'm unable to edit that value inside  apex:inputField. Here's my Apex code

```
    <apex:page standardController="Invoice_Statement__c">
      <apex:Form >

         <h1>Congratulations</h1><br/><br/>
         Hello,<b>{!$User.FirstName}</b><br/>
         Invoice Value is <apex:inputField value="{!Invoice_Statement__c.Invoice_Value__c}" /><br/><br/>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Update Invoice Value"/>

      </apex:Form>
   </apex:page>
```

Comment: Field is editable to the profile you're testing with right ?

Comment: Isn't it turned on by default ?

Comment: go check .. just trying to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Can you tell me where to check that field. I'm little confused.

Comment: Field level security for the field